# How to unit test the following function in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

```
I have a following code:

    angular
        .module('testApp')
        .factory('testDataService', function ($http) {
            function testDataService(){
                var self = this;
                self.test = function(){
                    //do something
                }

                self.test1 = function(){
                    // do something                
}
            }

            return new testDataService();

When I try to write a test case like 

    beforeEach(function(){
        new testDataService();
    });

It gives some error like:

> TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new testDataService()')
```

There are numerous functions such as "test", "test1", etc.. inside testDataService. I am not able to test the remaining functions because the scope of the outer function is unreachable. I am not able to get the instance because of "var self=this"
    Please help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to test? Are you trying to test that your application can create your factory? Are you trying to test that your App Compiles? etc. This question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Not enough detail here to help you. Here's an example of testing a angular service. https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/components/version/version_test.js

Comment: Please read the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of new operator to create Object.

Please check this one

```
describe("\n\Testing factory", function () {
        var factTestDataService;

        beforeEach(inject(function (testDataService) {
           factTestDataService= testDataService;
        }))


        it("factTestDataService test to defined",function(){

            expect(factTestDataService.test()).toBeDefined()
        })
        it("factTestDataService test1 to defined",function(){

            expect(factTestDataService.test1()).toBeDefined()
        })

         it("factTestDataService to defined",function(){

            expect(factTestDataService).toBeDefined()
        })          
    });
```

You need to inject **testDataService**   factory and store it in local var.

Then you can use this one to  access the method defined in that factory as you do  in angular and can check with different Jasmine test method.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory already returns a new instance of `testDataService`. There's no need for calling `new`. When you try to call `new` on an instance it throws the error you see.